# $f(x) = \sqrt{ |x|} - \log (1+|x|)$ has no Upper Bound on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is the following  function bounded on  $\mathbb R$ ?

$f(x) = \sqrt {|x|} - \log (1+|x|)$

My Attempt:  I can prove that $f(x) $ is an increasing function on $(0 , \infty)$ and $f(x) $ is decreasing on $(-\infty ,0)$ and $f(x) $ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $f(x) \geq 0$  for all $x \in  \mathbb R$. But I can not proceed further.

Can anyone please give me any hint or some thing?

Comment: It might be easier to look at $e^{f(x)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ x = e^{k}-1$ where $ k >> 2$.

Then $ \sqrt{x} > e^{k/2} - 1$ and $ \log (1 + x) = k$, and clearly $e^{k/2} - k  - 1 $ tends to infinity.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: use (prove) the fact that for any $M > 0$ there is $X > 0$ that for all $x > X$

$$ x^\frac{1}{2} > M + log(1 + x)$$

Comment: How do you go about proving this is the real question.

Comment: for example take $X = M^4$ or something similar